# How to update the branched forked repo?

Tags: github

How can I update a repo on github using git bash which is forked and after fork I have created another branch on it.

I want to update that branch.

I have create a branch locally with the aim of pushing to your remote fork.

Comment: Please provide more details in regards to the remote (GitHub) repo vs your repo. Did you create a branch locally with the aim of pushing to your remote fork? Do you want to apply changes to the original repository you forked from?

Please edit your question so that it is clearer what your goal is.